# Linux, список служб и список драйверов. Реализация на С++

Tags: c++, linux

Если я правильно понял, то для получения списка всех запущенных процессов можно использовать не встроенную команду `systemctl list-units --type service -all`, а просматривать директории `proc`.

Какие директории нужно просматривать в *Linux Ubuntu* для того, чтобы получить информацию о всех зарегистрированных службах и информацию о зарегистрированных драйверах в *Linux Ubuntu* на С++, просматривая определенные папки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`systemctl list-units --type service -all` показывает список всех "сервисов", а запущенных программ может быть на порядок больше. Но если система не systemd (сейчас это SlackWare, Gentoo (OpenRC сборка) и [Devuan](https://devuan.org/)), то такая команда не отработает - ее просто нет.

Просмотр всех "сервисов" на systemd системах - нужно смотреть [следующие каталоги](https://habr.com/company/southbridge/blog/255845/)

- `/usr/lib/systemd/system/` – юниты из установленных пакетов — всякие nginx, apache, mysql и прочее
- `/run/systemd/system/` — юниты, созданные в рантайме
- `/etc/systemd/system/` — юниты, созданные системным администратором.

А файлы можно парсить и смотреть.

Теперь к "драйверам". Вообще то они не драйвера, а модули. И они не "зарегестрированнные", а "инсталлированные". Что бы их посмотреть, можно запустить команду `lsmod`. Ручками - посмотреть файл `/proc/modules`. Значение столбиков

- первый - имя модуля
- второй - размер модуля в памяти, в байтах
- третий - сколько раз модуль загружен в память, ноль - выгружен
- четвертый - зависимые модули
- пятый - состояние модуля, только  Live (работает), Loading (загружается), or Unloading (выгружается)
- шестой - адрес/смещение в памяти, для отладочных целей

Узнать предназначение модуля - это отдельная задача.

Comment: А можно просто открыть код `lsof`.